# Weird result when finding ripple bounds of RC circuit with square wave input

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, pwm

If \$V_{ext}\$ is applied to a RC circuit, then voltage across capacitor is given by:   $$v(t) = V_{ext} + (V_i -V_{ext})e^{-t/RC} $$

Using above to find the ripple bounds \$v_l\$ and \$v_h\$, get two equations:
$$v_h=A + (v_l - A)e^{-aT/RC}$$
$$v_l = 0 + (v_h-0)e^{-(T-aT)/RC}$$

Where \$A,T, a\$ are the *amplitude*, *period*, duty cycle of the input square wave.
Eliminating \$v_l\$ gives:
$$\color{blue}{A(1-e^{-aT/RC})} = \color{purple}{v_h(1-e^{-T/RC})}$$

If I'm looking at it correctly,
the left side represents:
\$\color{blue}{\text{voltage charged by the capacitor in time $aT$ when external dc voltage is $A$.  }}\$
the right side represents:
\$\color{purple}{\text{voltage charged by the capacitor in time $T$ when external dc voltage is $v_h$.  }}\$

The equation above says these two voltages are EQUAL!
Is this a coincidence or something interesting going on here? I'm not able to see further *why* they are equal... Love to hear your insights!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR1uTm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Your reduction equivalence is incorrect as the Vavg steadystate rise to the duty cycle ratio of A with T time constant.

Comment: Get the average (vh+vl)/2= d*A… or aA

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 ty working on it... wil get back 10 min

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'm getting $$\frac{v_h+v_l}{2} = \frac{A}{2}(1-e^{-aT/RC})$$

not sure where im doing wrong. still working... ty:)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the average value is not simplifying to \$aA\$ :( but my equations are actually giving correct values for the ripple bounds \$v_h, v_l:  3.11, 1.89\$.  [kindly see this wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285*%281-e%5E%28-1%2F2%29%29%2F%281-e%5E%28-1%29%29%2C+5*%281-e%5E%28-1%2F2%29%29%2F%281-e%5E%28-1%29%29*e%5E%28-1%2F2%29%29)

Comment: Yes that’s ok, but  you can see result  in simulation is 50% A.  Try integration. And of course (3.11+1.89)/2=2.5

Comment: Exactly! feels something  wrong in my work. have to think more clearly... thank you for suggesting to find the average value.. you're awesome:) @TonyStewartEE75

Comment: Exactly! feels something  wrong in my work. have to think more clearly... thank you for suggesting to find the average value:)

Comment: For exponential , current flips polarity with 0V pulse, integration over a much longer period than 2T gives the average or simply the duty factor of (a * vh + ( 1-a) vl ) * A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential terms on the two sides of the equations are **not** the same. You only have equality if the duty factor is 1, which means that you have a step input rather than a rectangular wave.

This makes sense. If the input is a step that stays high then the capacitor voltage will eventually be equal to \$A\$, the input voltage.

Comment: Right, \$A, v_h\$ are thought of as dc voltage sources.. but in that equation \$T\$ is constant, not the variable time \$t\$. I think that equation is an identity, not sure with terminology... there are no variables in that equation...

Comment: Yes, there is the variable \$a\$, the duty factor of the waveform.